# Firefox fails to open url when using webdriver python API

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am new to python and trying to build a selenium code to open a website via firefox.
I am using a debian stretch machine for the tests. The versions of the tools are given below :

> geckodriver 0.24.0 ( 2019-01-28) ,  Python 2.7.13 ,  Mozilla Firefox 52.7.3 , selenium (3.141.0)

I see that the firefox window opens( even though in headless). But it doesnt proceed further with opening the website. The firefox instance waits for sometime after opening and then stops, the script gives error like

> WebHandle.open_application("Firefox" , "http://www.google.com")
> File "/home/yyyyy/yyyyy/yyyyy/yyyyy/script.py", line 49, in open_application
> driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in **init**
> keep_alive=True)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
> self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
> response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused

Code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

        options = FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        print (" * Opening firefox session")
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
        driver.maximize_window()
        print(driver.title)
```

While looking into the geckodriver.log , I see the following errors

> 1624193615192 mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.Wwi0327B9dAL"
> 1624193616996   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828

> [Child 28357] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /build/firefox-esr-52.7.3esr/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2152
> [Child 28357] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file /build/firefox-esr-52.7.3esr/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2152

> ###!!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x3E0003,name=PCompositable::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv
> ###!!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x3E0003,name=PCompositable::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

Thanks already for any help in fixing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `geckodriver.exe` file in a separate folder & drive and updating the path in `executable_path`. 
eg:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = options, executable_path=r"D:/Python/drivers/geckodriver.exe")
```